# asterisk in formula with many variables: how to limit order of interactions?

Tags: r, formula

Suppose I have a list of variables names `x = c('a','b','c','d','e')` for a statistical model. When building the [formula](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html), it's nice to use something like `paste('y ~',paste(x,collapse=' + '))` to get `y ~ a + b + c + d + e`, especially when `x` may change.

Now I'd like to do the same thing with interaction terms, but `paste(x,collapse=' : ')` produces `a : b : c : d : e`, which is only one term, and `paste(x,collapse=' * ')` produces `a * b * c * d * e`, which includes all possible interactions across all orders -- i.e. `a + b + c + ... + a:b + a:c + ... a:b:c + a:b:d + ... + a:b:c:d:e`. How can I limit the order of interaction terms up to say, 2nd, e.g. `a:b` ?

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward way to achieve this, assuming you want to cross all terms to a specified degree, is to use the `^` operator in the formula.

```
x = c('a','b','c','d','e')

# Build formula using reformulate
(fm <- reformulate(x, "y"))
y ~ a + b + c + d + e

# Cross to second degree  
(fm2 <- update(fm, ~ .^2))
y ~ a + b + c + d + e + a:b + a:c + a:d + a:e + b:c + b:d + b:e + 
c:d + c:e + d:e

# Terms of f2 as character:
attr(terms.formula(fm2), "term.labels")
[1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "d"   "e"   "a:b" "a:c" "a:d" "a:e" "b:c" "b:d" "b:e" "c:d" "c:e" "d:e"

# Cross to third degree
(fm3 <- update(fm, ~ .^3))
y ~ a + b + c + d + e + a:b + a:c + a:d + a:e + b:c + b:d + b:e + 
    c:d + c:e + d:e + a:b:c + a:b:d + a:b:e + a:c:d + a:c:e + 
    a:d:e + b:c:d + b:c:e + b:d:e + c:d:e
```

Comment: Nice - and for programmatic use, you can do `update(fm, substitute(~.^n, list(n = 3)))`, etc. Much better than hacking with `combn`.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I didn't read `?formula` closely enough re. the use of `^`. Based on your solution, my preferred implementation is `paste('(',paste(x,collapse=' + '),')^',n)`. However, this does not (easily) support omitting lower order terms as in my solution below.

Comment: @jessexknight I guess it depends on your use case and how complex the formula you're trying to build is.  You can do `update(fm, ~ .^3 - .^2)` to obtain the result of your last example. If you wanted to omit two way but keep the main effects and three way interactions you could use `update(fm, ~ .^3 - .^2 + .)`.

Answer (score 3):

`reformulate` handles this problem quite naturally, though how you would apply it is context-dependent.

If you want to drop interactions of order greater than `order_max` from an existing formula, then you can do:

```r
f1 <- function(formula, order_max) {
    a <- attributes(terms(formula))
    reformulate(termlabels = a$term.labels[a$order <= order_max], 
                response = if (r <- a$response) a$variables[[1L + r]],
                intercept = a$intercept,
                env = environment(formula))
}

f1(y ~ a * b * c * d * e, 2L)
## y ~ a + b + c + d + e + a:b + a:c + b:c + a:d + b:d + c:d + a:e + 
##     b:e + c:e + d:e
```

If you have a character vector `x` listing names of variables, and you want to construct a formula containing their interactions up to order `order_max`, then you can do:

***Edit:** Never mind - follow @RitchieSacramento's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71137184/12685768) and use the `^` operator in this case.*

```r
f2 <- function(x, order_max, response = NULL, intercept = TRUE, env = parent.frame()) {
    paste1 <- function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ":")
    combn1 <- function(n) if (n > 1L) combn(x, n, paste1) else x
    termlabels <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(order_max), combn1), FALSE, FALSE)
    reformulate(termlabels = termlabels, response = response,
                intercept = intercept, env = env)
}

f2(letters[1:5], 2L, response = quote(y))
## y ~ a + b + c + d + e + a:b + a:c + a:d + a:e + b:c + b:d + b:e + 
##     c:d + c:e + d:e
```

To be parsed correctly, nonsyntactic variable names must be protected with backquotes:

```r
f2(c("`!`", "`?`"), 1L, response = quote(`#`))
## `#` ~ `!` + `?`
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I don't understand the utility of casting everything as a formula up front, just to worry about intercept and response. It is out of scope. I prefer my own `iterms` solution below, which can be easily combined with other strings to give the final formula like `f = formula(paste('y ~',iterms(x,n)))`

Comment: `?formula` states: "`eval(call("~", quote(foo + bar)))` has been an order of magnitude more efficient than `formula(c("~", "foo + bar"))`". In general, operating on the language at the level of strings is slow and error prone. That is why language objects and operators on language objects exist.

Comment: If you want to combine the right hand sides of two formulae `f1 = y ~ a + b` and `f2 = ~c + d`, then there is `update(f1, substitute(~.+.., list(.. = f2[[2L]])))`.

Comment: I couldn't find that quote in `?formula`. Also, I cannot imagine a situation where evaluating the formula expression is a performance bottleneck compared to fitting the model. Interested to learn what kind of errors can arise.

Comment: Hmm - I see it in R-devel [here](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/d0239dc900f3a48d93b0f4347c000ade98e8a854/src/library/stats/man/formula.Rd#L130-L132) and in R 4.1.2. The danger mostly lies with nonsyntactic names and operator precedence. You would need to take care to put backquotes and parentheses in the right places, and the bookkeeping required to get it right can become nontrivial fast. In your use case, the difference might be negligible, but R package developers have to be worried about these things.

Comment: I see -- thanks for taking the time to explain. I'm on R 3.6.3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a another solution to create the `:` terms:

```
iterms = function(x,n,lower=TRUE){
  return(paste(lapply(ifelse(lower,1,n):n,function(ni){
    paste(apply(combn(x,ni),2,paste,collapse=':'),collapse=' + ')
  }),collapse=' + '))
}
```

Testing with:

```
x = c('a','b','c','d')
print(iterms(x,1))
print(iterms(x,2))
print(iterms(x,3))
print(iterms(x,3,lower=FALSE))
```

yields:

```
[1] "a + b + c + d"
[1] "a + b + c + d + a:b + a:c + a:d + b:c + b:d + c:d"
[1] "a + b + c + d + a:b + a:c + a:d + b:c + b:d + c:d + a:b:c + a:b:d + a:c:d + b:c:d"
[1] "a:b:c + a:b:d + a:c:d + b:c:d"
```